# Sum of distinc rows after a 1-many table join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sum

I have 2 tables that I am joining.

Table 1 has 1-many relationship with table 2. That is, table 2 can return multiple rows for a single row of table 1. Because of this, the records of table 1 is duplicated for as many rows as are on table 2.. which is expected.

Now, I have a sum on one of the columns from table 1, but because of the multiple rows that get returned on the join, the sum is obviously multiplying.

Is there a way to get this number back to its original number? I tried dividing by the count of rows from table 2 but this didnt quite give me the expected result. Are there any analytical functions that could do this? I almost want something like 
"if this row has not yet been counted in the sum, add it to the sum"

Comment: Table structure, query, example data and desired results would be handy.

Comment: @Lock:On what basis you are summing,if there is one to many relation in table1 to table2,because each row in table 1 will be distinct .Explain this with this data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/228ea/2

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly without example structures/data required results etc, but this may be what you are after:

```
Select
  s.t1Sum,
  t1.*,
  t2.*
From (
    Select
      sum(col1) as t1Sum
    From
      Table1
    ) s
    Cross Join
  Table1 t1
    Inner Join
  Table2 t2
    On t1.Id = t2.FkId
```

Comment: :I think this will not work because as far my understanding ,sum will be of the id's that matches with the table2.In your case you are doing sum of the whole `table1 col1`,which might not work.Even I am not sure about the requirement,but may be my understanding is correct.Sorry if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

There might be a far more optimized way of doing this,even i am not happy with the solution i am offering you now,but for a time being this will work for you .Let this be open for other Guru's:)

```
create table table1(id number,val number);
create table table2(id number,name varchar2(200));

insert into table1 values(1,1);
insert into table1 values(2,2);
insert into table1 values(3,3);

insert into table2 values(1,'gaurav');
insert into table2 values(1,'saurav');
insert into table2 values(1,'paurav');

insert into table2 values(2,'Rohan');
insert into table2 values(2,'Bhasker');
insert into table2 values(2,'Garima');


WITH tab as
(
SELECT id,sum(val) over() sum
FROM(
select DISTINCT t1.id,t1.val
from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id
))
SELECT tab.id,t2.id,t2.name,tab.sum
FROM table2 t2,tab
WHERE t2.id=tab.id
```

**SQLFIDDLE:**[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8077/40)